# Why were comments in my IS answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Related to [Why are IS referred to as “so-called”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23876/why-are-is-referred-to-as-so-called)

I had 2 comments below my answer that were not irrelevant and I'd like to add them to my answer as an update. The comments were deleted. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing these are the comments you are talking about:

> NO. They are not. its Cartoon of Islam not strict Islam. they read only war verses; not verses like this: [Say, "O People of the Scripture, come to a word that is equitable between us and you - that we will not worship except Allah and not associate anything with Him and not take one another as lords instead of Allah ." But if they turn away, then say, "Bear witness that we are Muslims](https://quran.com/3/64)
>
> ... and they dont consider verses like this: [There shall be no compulsion in acceptance of the religion. The right course has become clear from the wrong](https://quran.com/2/256) ...

I didn't delete the comments, but looking at the comment history I see that both were replies to another comment that was flagged as rude. When that comment was removed, both your comments became obsolete. There was no reason to keep them around.

Comments can be deleted at any time, for any reason. Please do not count on them sticking around. If you have valuable information to add to one of your posts answer, don't waste your time commenting, just update the post.

**Related**

- [What are comments?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)
- [LOTS of comments being deleted](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/289/101)
- [Would it be possible to refrain from unilaterally deleting comment threads *without preserving the comments*?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/would-it-be-possible-to-refrain-from-unilaterally-deleting-comment-threads-with)

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to add [tag:faq] to [LOTS of comments being deleted](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/289/11249)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker added [faq-proposed] for now, will elevate to [faq] if it keeps coming up (and we don't get a better duplicate in the mean time).